# Out of breath in Eretz Yisroel

Tags: sources-mekorot, eretz-yisrael

I once heard in the name of the Gerrer Rebbe (Imrei Emes) 2 explanations as to why people get easily out of breath while walking in Eretz Yisroel

(1. Since there is a Mitzva to walk 4 Amos in Eretz Yisroel (source is a Pnei Yeshua in Bava Metzia), therefore the שטן will make it difficult to accomplish it as not to accumulate too many Mitzvos.
2. Based on the Gemara Kesubos 112a that Eretz Yisroel is like a 'stretched out' piece of land like the hide of a deer, so in essence one is walking more distance of land then he thinks!!)

Does anyone have a source either to this Imrei Emes, or to this concept of breathlessness in the holy land??

Comment: Seems like a direct consequence of אוירא דארץ ישראל מחכים and לא יגעתי ומצאתי אל תאמן

Comment: I don't remember walking so much or so happily as when I was in Israel